# hover an image that has a hover effect and also show text in another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have 4 images (responsive/collapsing to 2 and to 1) that have a hover effect and link applied to them. Below them there should be a div (or an alternative solution) that displays the description to each image when hovered over that specific image. So 4 different texts for 4 images and I would very much like to keep the hover effect.

The code I have working for me so far is:

```
<div class="wrapper grid4">
   <div id="werk-1">
      <article class="col">
         <div class= "hover"><a href="VREESMACHINE.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/vreesmachine-330px.jpg" width="100%" /></a></div>
      </article>
      <article class="col">
         <div class= "hover"><a href="PRINTWERK.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/ted-330px.jpg" width="100%" /></a></div>
      </article>
      <article class="col">
         <div class= "hover"><a href="TEKENINGEN.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/grootel-330.jpg" width="100%" /></a></div>
      </article>
      <article class="col">
         <div class= "hover"><a href="BOEKEN.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/haai-330px.jpg" width="100%" /></a></div>
      </article>
      <div>
         <div class="grafischewerktekst">THE SPECIFIC TEXT TO DISPLAY</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the code does not display properly in my question so I will try again:

Comment: Can you provide more code ? Because it's hard to help you with that information

Comment: This is better - well what I mean is this is the complete code for this particular part

Comment: Where's the jQuery and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `data-*` attribute to each article with class `.col` and a `mouseover` event to the same which changes text of `.grafischewerktekst` div to the one present in `data-*`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m87org4m/)**

```js
$('.col').on('mouseover',function()
{
    $('.grafischewerktekst').text($(this).attr('data-desc'))
});
```

```css
img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper grid4">
   <div id="werk-1">
      <article class="col" data-desc="Image 1 description"><!--add your image description to data-desc-->
         <div class= "hover"><a href="VREESMACHINE.html"><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rZmCIp0C-hQ/Tx6aCFeweoI/AAAAAAAAAnQ/WqIEVBTIzRk/s1600/Cool-Tiger-Wallpaper-1920x1080-HD.jpg" width="100%" /></a></div>
      </article>
      <article class="col" data-desc="Image 2 description">
         <div class= "hover"><a href="PRINTWERK.html"><img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/01/06/2473100D00000578-2898639-Photographer_Andrey_Gudkov_snapped_the_images_on_the_plains_of_t-a-20_1420546215677.jpg" width="100%" /></a></div>
      </article>
      <article class="col" data-desc="Image 3 description">
         <div class= "hover"><a href="TEKENINGEN.html"><img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03025/saatchi-plug-hole_3025834k.jpg" width="100%" /></a></div>
      </article>
      <article class="col" data-desc="Image 4 description">
         <div class= "hover"><a href="BOEKEN.html"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MHxFnsPcldo/T6wD3La83DI/AAAAAAAAGSI/W9KKoTN2NVk/s1600/anaconda-Python-1.jpg" width="100%" /></a></div>
      </article>
      <div>
         <div class="grafischewerktekst">THE SPECIFIC TEXT TO DISPLAY</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the SWIFT replies - I have tested the one from Guruprasad because the snippet was exactly what I am looking for. however I haven't succeeded in getting it to work - just copied it and pasted it. I have put the jqeurie just above it in the code (between <script></script> could that be the problem?

Comment: check for console error in your page!! and better to place `script` just before `</body>`

Comment: I am still recovering from the initial shock - that was the trick, works like a charm - I don't now how to thank you. I am from Holland and are -believe it or not- suffering from a heatwave and you made and saved my DAY! Thank you so very much!

Comment: @FransGoris.. Anytime.. Glad it helped! You can mark it as answer if it helped your.. :) Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Could you help me with one more thing - I want the text to fade in and added this: 
    $('.grafischewerktekst').text($(this).attr('data-desc'))
    $('.grafischewerktekst').text($(this).attr('data-desc')).fadeIn('slow') - but this does not work nor does simply adding .fadeIn('slow') just after the ('data-desc')) part - could you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: @FransGoris.. Like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m87org4m/1/)**? I have commented the 2nd line in the `demo`. If you want different effect then comment the other one and uncomment 2nd line!

Comment: It seems to conflict with the hover effect I already have for the image so I will leave it like it is - but my thanks again, much apreciated - I now kind of get to see how such a code is built up.

Comment: Anyways!! Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly:

Each image has some description, on hover it will take that description text and display it in your 'grafischewerktekst' class.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper grid4">
  <div id="werk-1" style="width: 400px;">
    <article class="col">
      <div class= "hover"><a href="VREESMACHINE.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/vreesmachine-330px.jpg" width="100%" /></a>
        <div class="description" style="display: none;">THE SPECIFIC TEXT TO DISPLAY 1</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="col">
      <div class= "hover"><a href="PRINTWERK.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/ted-330px.jpg" width="100%" /></a>
        <div class="description" style="display: none;">THE SPECIFIC TEXT TO DISPLAY 2</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="col">
      <div class= "hover"><a href="TEKENINGEN.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/grootel-330.jpg" width="100%" /></a>
        <div class="description" style="display: none;">THE SPECIFIC TEXT TO DISPLAY 3</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="col">
      <div class= "hover"><a href="BOEKEN.html"><img src="afbeeldingen/haai-330px.jpg" width="100%" /></a>
        <div class="description" style="display: none;">THE SPECIFIC TEXT TO DISPLAY 4</div>
      </div>
    </article>
      <div><div class="grafischewerktekst">THE SPECIFIC TEXT TO DISPLAY</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
   $('.hover').hover(function(){
    $('.grafischewerktekst').html($(this).find('.description').html());
   }, function(){
    $('.grafischewerktekst').html('');
   });
```